# Connection pooling and multi-threaded applications

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

Can connection pooling be used only in multi-threaded or multi-process applications?

Is it possible to make use of connection pooling in web application implemented using PHP and MySQL? 
If yes, please provide an example of such an application.